# Do Projections have Sections

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

Let $n,m>0$ be positive integers and let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ take $(x,y)$ to $x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$; i.e.: the canonical projection.

Then, does $\pi$ have a section?  Ie.: a continuous right-inverse?

Comment: What have you tried? What does a "section" mean to you?

Comment: It does have, e.g. the canonical  first injection $x\longmapsto (x,0)$.

Comment: Try visualizing this for $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose your favorite continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$. Its graph is the subset $\Gamma(f)\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m$ given by $\{(x,y):y=f(x)\}$. This gives a section of the projection $\pi:\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m\to \Bbb{R}^n$ by $\sigma_f(x)=(x,f(x))$. So, sections (of trivial bundles) can be visualized as graphs of continuous functions. In fact, given a section
$$ \sigma:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m$$
applying the projection to $\Bbb{R}^m$ we get a function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ so that $\sigma_f=\sigma$. In particular, continuous sections of the trivial bundle $\Bbb{R}^n\times \Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ are in bijective correspondence with continuous functions $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  A vector field is a nice example of that.  It is a smooth section of the tangent bundle.